How to resize a video in video editing to a certain resolution
I know where the scale tab is at in blender video editor, but there’s no scaling by pixels option. Is there something I can use to match a certain resolution?

do you mean, to show a video at a different resolution than the render size set in the Blender render settings tab? like, to have a video playing without filling the screen for example?

It's really not straightforward, but if you know the original resolution you can do it like this:

With the video strip selected go to the Strip properties tab and open the Transform panel.

In front of Scale click and hold to select both X and Y fields.

Enter the desired pixel size divided by the original size (height or width doesn't matter):
ie: 480/1080


